# Detecting and Redirecting

Tags: javascript, redirect

I use a JavaScript to detect Java and Symbian and android mobile and to detect PD

```
<script>

var isAndroidMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/android/i);
    }
};

var isSymbianMobile = {
    Symbian: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/series60|symbian/i);
    }
};

var isJavaMobile = {
    Java: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/java|mdp|J2ME|midp|UC/i);
    }
};

var isPc = {
    Pc: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/windows|linux|centos|ubuntu/i);
    }
};

if( isJavaMobile.Java() ) alert('You are useing java mobile!');
    {{ window.location = 'http://domain/prog.jar' }}
if( isSymbianMobile.Symbian() ) alert('You are useing symbian mobile!');
    {{ window.location = 'http://domain/prog.sisx' }}
if( isPc.Pc() ) alert('You are useing Pc!');
    {{ window.location = 'http://domain/prog.exe' }}
if( isAndroidMobile.Android() ) alert('You are useing android mobile!');
    {{ window.location = 'http://domain/prog.apk' }}

</script>
```

But when it's detect pc or Java or Symbian it's redirect it to Android

If I set

```
if( isSymbianMobile.Symbian() ) alert('You are useing symbian mobile!');
    {{ window.location = 'http://domain/prog.sisx' }}
if( isPc.Pc() ) alert('You are useing Pc!');
    {{ window.location = 'http://domain/prog.exe' }}
if( isAndroidMobile.Android() ) alert('You are useing android mobile!');
    {{ window.location = 'http://domain/prog.apk' }}
if( isJavaMobile.Java() ) alert('You are useing java mobile!');
    {{ window.location = 'http://domain/prog.jar' }}
```

It will be redirect it to Java

when I put this Java code in the end it will be redirect to Java
and when I put this Symbian code in the end it will be redirect to Symbian and so on.

Can I fix this problem?

Comment: Not commenting on the UA detection but your redirects are not bound inside the `if` statements (what's the `{{}}` for?) and assigning to `window.location` will not necessarily stop further script execution so if you have multiple matches for different conditions the last one will execute.

Answer (score 0):

Looks as though your JavaScript is just broken. Try changing it so that the `alert` and the `window.location` are within the `if` statement.

```
if( isJavaMobile.Java() ) {
    alert('You are useing java mobile!');
    window.location = 'http://domain/prog.jar' ;
}
if( isSymbianMobile.Symbian() ) {
    alert('You are useing symbian mobile!');
    window.location = 'http://domain/prog.sisx';
}
if( isPc.Pc() ) {
    alert('You are useing Pc!');
    window.location = 'http://domain/prog.exe';
}
if( isAndroidMobile.Android() ) {
    alert('You are useing android mobile!');
    window.location = 'http://domain/prog.apk';
}
```

Comment: how can I detect all java mobile ??